# Create indicator variable to detect string in any column that begins with word in R

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I have a dataset with many columns.  I am interested in the columns that contain "dx_" within the variable name.  I would like to create an indicator variable that is 1 in every row where at least one of the columns' whose names contain "dx_" has a value that starts with "493".  For example:

```
df = data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),var2 = c(5,4,3,2,1),dx_1 = c("493","XH","1493","4938B","LP23"),dx_2 = c("AB","0PC3","MNP","12GT","FPN2"),a_dx_3 = c("FTR","2RTN","92KS","J294","493V"))

> df
  var1 var2  dx_1 dx_2 a_dx_3
1    1    5   493   AB    FTR
2    2    4    XH 0PC3   2RTN
3    3    3  1493  MNP   92KS
4    4    2 4938B 12GT   J294
5    5    1  LP23 FPN2   493V
```

I would like to create a new variable, `Z`, that is 1 if any of `dx_1`, `dx_2`, or `a_dx_3` have a value that starts with "493" in that row, or 0 otherwise.  However, I need the solution to be flexible so can I don't have to specify which columns beyond saying `contains("dx_")`

I would like my answer to look like this:

```
  var1 var2  dx_1 dx_2 a_dx_3 Z
1    1    5   493   AB    FTR 1
2    2    4    XH 0PC3   2RTN 0
3    3    3  1493  MNP   92KS 0
4    4    2 4938B 12GT   J294 1
5    5    1  LP23 FPN2   493V 1
```

This is my failed attempt:  First I create a helper function to recognize the string:

```
detect_493_fn <- function(str){
  ans = if_else(str_starts(str,"493") == TRUE,
                1,
                0)
  return(ans)
}
```

And then use a combination of if_any, across, and contains:

```
ans <- df %>%
  mutate(Z = case_when(
    if_any(across(contains("dx_"), ~detect_493_fn(.))) ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0))
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `Z = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `if_any()`:
! Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `tbl_df<
  dx_1  : double
  dx_2  : double
  a_dx_3: double
>`.
i It must be numeric or character.
```

I would be so grateful if someone could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(Z = as.numeric(if_any(contains("dx"), str_starts, "493")))

  var1 var2  dx_1 dx_2 a_dx_3 Z
1    1    5   493   AB    FTR 1
2    2    4    XH 0PC3   2RTN 0
3    3    3  1493  MNP   92KS 0
4    4    2 4938B 12GT   J294 1
5    5    1  LP23 FPN2   493V 1
```

Consider keeping your `Z` variable as logical.  `if_any()` is an `across()` variant so you use it in place of `across()` not with it.